# Probability 3 events

Tags: probability

Have a target that has 4 sections. Call them A, B, C, D.

you throw there rocks one at a time, if they land outside the target or in a section that has aready got a rock in it you throw again without penalty.
You need to get a rock in A, B & C.  What would the size of the sections be if you needed to have a probability of 1% to 5%?

So could throw the following.
ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA - giving 6 possible ways to get the rocks in the spots  You would fail if any of the rocks landed in D.

This is where I got lost.

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that $A,B,C$ are all the same size and have a $p$ chance of being hit.  Then $D$ has a $1-3p$ chance of being hit.  The chance that the first rock doesn't hit $D$ is $3p$.  The chance that the second rock that counts doesn't hit $D$ is $\frac {2p}{1-p}$  After two have been hit, the chance the third rock that counts doesn't hit $D$ is $\frac p{1-2p}$, so the total chance is $\frac {6p^3}{(1-p)(1-2p)}$  We want this to be in the range $0.01$ to $0.05$, which [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.01=x%5E3/%281-x%29/%281-2x%29) says should have $p\approx 17.5\%$ [to](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.05=x%5E3/%281-x%29/%281-2x%29) $26.1\%$

It doesn't seem required that $A,B,C$ be the same size, so could find many other solutions.